# For some reason the post method doesn't work for me

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Hello I am trying to submit a form from my site, and get it using post method, for some reason it puts a null value in me, why? I will note that if I send not on form but reading axios it works.

```js
app.post("/insert", async (req, res) => {
  const {
    nameInvstement,
    moneyinvstement,
    placeinvstement,
    moreDetails,
    image
  } = req.body;
  try {
    await collection.insertOne({
      nameInvstement,
      moneyinvstement,
      placeinvstement,
      moreDetails,
      image
    });
    res.status(200).json("OK");
  } catch (e) {
    res.send(e);
  }
});
```

Comment: Two questions... 1) What body-parsing middleware are you using (if any)? 2) How are you submitting the data from the front-end?

Comment: can you share your axios request aswell

Answer (score 0):

I use the vue.js directory, and I pass it data in v-model. It's the axios that work for me.
And before that's the form that doesn't work for me.
Thanks so much to everyone for the help.

```html
<form action="http://localhost:3000/insert" method="POST" class="card">
      <div><label for="nameinvstement">:שם השקעה</label></div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="nameInvstement" id="nameinvstement" required />
      </div>
      <div><label for="moneyinvstement">:סכום השקעה</label></div>
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="moneyinvstement"
          id="moneyinvstement"
          required
        />
      </div>
      <div><label for="placeinvstement">:מיקום ההשקעה</label></div>
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="placeinvstement"
          id="placeinvstement"
          required
        />
      </div>
      <div><label for="moreDetails">:עוד פירוט</label></div>
      <div>
        <textarea
          cols="23"
          rows="7"
          maxlength="200"
          name="moreDetails"
          id="moreDetails"
          required
        ></textarea>
      </div>
      <label for="image"> בחר תמונה של ההשקעה</label>
      <div><input type="file" name="image" required /></div>
      <br />
      <div><button >שלח</button></div>
    </form>
```

```html
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      name: "",
      email: "",
      password: "",
      elswitch: true
    };
  },
  methods: {
    postNewUser() {
      this.$http
        .post(URL, {
          name: this.name,
          email: this.email,
          password: this.password,
          elswitch: this.elswitch
        })
        .then(function(res) {
          res.status(200).json("OK");
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
      this.$message({
        message: "תודה רבה!!! הרישום הושלם בהצלחה",
        type: "success"
      });
    }
  }
};
```